# Support the Area51 literature proposal!

Tags: discussion, area51

If you haven't already, I would like to encourage you to take a moment to support the [Area51 literature proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature?referrer=JZwS-YfNZmxD4yRnMOivZg2) by...

1. Following the proposal.
2. Writing example questions.
3. Voting on other example questions.

There have been [various](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80865/literature) [attempts](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6426/literature) to create a Stack Exchange site dedicated to literature, but unfortunately these attempts have not been successful, [mostly due to a lack of effort on the part of the supporters of the proposals](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22393/36412). The latest literature proposal has been doing great (31 followers in nine days), but I don't want it to lose steam halfway through the Area51 process, and become yet another failed literature proposal.

That's why I'm reaching out to the Science Fiction and Fantasy community on Stack Exchange and asking for their support. I'm sure most of you enjoy reading books that aren't science fiction or fantasy, and I'm sure most of you occasionally have questions about those books that you would like answered (or have answers to questions that you would like to write). If the latest literature proposal is successful, then we will finally have a place on the Stack Exchange network where you can receive answers to these burning questions.

**[So don't wait! Support the literature proposal today!](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature?referrer=JZwS-YfNZmxD4yRnMOivZg2)**

<sub>A moderator [gave me permission](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26233372#26233372) to write this meta post.</sub>

Comment: Have y'all made a [Community Promo Ad](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5326/community-promotion-ads-2015)?

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing if the downvoters dislike the proposal or the way it is being advertised, or other.

Comment: I'll be the first upvoter of this question (having already followed the proposal a while back).

Comment: Flagged as spam (I can't vote to close here). While I hope the site gets going, this isn't the way to promote it.  Maybe a brief mention on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) would be acceptable.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I didn't read the fine print that this was moderator approved. That said, this still isn't the right forum for this, IMO.

Comment: If the community decides that this question is inappropriate, I won't be offended if it is removed or deleted.

Comment: @GreenMatt - sorry, I disagree. This may not be 100% cleanly ontopic here (as it doesn't discuss SFF.SE), but neither are posts commemorating Sir Christipher Lee (which was deemed ontopic) and many other posts that have very little to do with discussing the main site. My suspicion (and my reason) is that this is because this Meta is also for discussing topics about this **community**, not just the technical site; and Literature.SE is very much of interest to a SFF community at large. IMHO.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - I downvoted for a couple of reasons; 1) This is spam. Admittedly for something else within the network but spam nonetheless and 2) I don't support the proposal. It's been tried before (more than once) and has failed before. It's just too broad a topic.

Comment: For the record, I also fear that a generic literature site will a) Splinter off scifi book questions that would be better asked here b) Descend into a generic "*what book am I trying to remember*" site.

Comment: Time to update this question? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

As someone who was pretty excited to have a literature.SE before and saddended when it was shuttered, I wholeheartedly support the **idea**.

However, before I support the **proposal** (and I suspect others like me), I would strongly suggest that you explicitly elaborate on stated reasons for original literature.SE demise, and how the new propsal proposed (no pun intended) to deal with the issues?

---

The reason to be cautious is because my support of Area 51 proposals is a **very scarse resource** - because you're limited to committing to only 3 Area 51 sites at a time by Area 51 rules.

As such, it forces people to be VERY careful with deciding which sites to commit to.

Comment: Hi DVK. Thank you for your question: [I wrote up an answer on Area51](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/22393/36412) (where it would be seen by more people) that I think addresses your concerns. If you have any additional questions, please feel free to leave a comment, either here or on Area51. Also, the proposal is in the definition phase, not the commitment phase, so you can follow the proposal (and vote on questions) without committing to the site.